# null object after valueEventListener

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am using `Firebase` `valueEventListener` and adding objects in `OnDataChange`. But my list stays null. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase listeners fetch data asynchronously. Add your objects in the list in the `OnDataChange` method itself. And notify the adapter by `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`